# Automation Studio - Export activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, email-alert, process-automation

I need to set - up an email alert notification once an export to data lake fails. This is especially interesting when an export fails on the last day of the month. If no notification is being sent, we could possibly miss data from the last day of that month.

I know that there's an automation functionalities (send notification if automation errors), but is there any other ways? I was also looking into the automation instance object but I am not sure how to implement this!

Comment: Have you tried this ... 1) [Automation Studio Notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_get_automation_studio_notifications.htm&type=5)

Comment: What is your criteria for failure? That the exported data fails completely, that it doesn't contain certain information, or isn't over/under a certain file size? I would define what you term failure first, then go from there. If you can add to the question, I can pose a few solutions.